# Are clouds aerosol?

Tags: meteorology, clouds, aerosol

I recently came across a science writer's page according to which clouds are liquid water. I pointed out to this author that in reality clouds are made up of a dispersion of water micro-droplets in a gas and therefore are aerosols from the physical-chemistry point of view. I received a rather abrupt answer and therefore I wonder if slightly different definitions apply in the field of meteorology than in physical-chemistry. So my question is: how is defined the state of a cloud in meteorology, is it a liquid or an aerosol?

quoting Wikipedia:

"An aerosol is a suspension of fine solid particles or liquid droplets in air or another gas".

"A liquid is a nearly incompressible fluid that conforms to the shape of its container but retains a nearly constant volume independent of pressure".

Comment: Looks like fog is often termed an aerosol, so that would well support your thinking.

Comment: If they are made of liquid droplets then would marking it as an aerosol not simply be *more specific*? Although, to be honest, I'm pretty sure that ice also exists inside of clouds so in that case "aerosols" would also be more correct.